# Android GridView Item Click Event Handler Inside ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-gridview

I have an Android GridView inside an ExpandableListView. All data is appearing fine but I can not find a way to handle GridView Item Click event. I just want to open up another Intent upon clicking on a grid's cell and pass a value to the intent.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
YourGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this,
                            MyNewActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Make sure in your GridLayout there is no clickable content like buttons otherwise they'll fired instead of this

Answer (score 0):

> grid.setOnChildClickListener();

may solve your problem!